# Can I USE Razor Engine in Asp.Net WebSite Project

Tags: asp.net, razor

I Have an old asp.net website project, it compile at runtime webpages *.aspx .
Can I use Razor engine without MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can! 
The maximum version for this configuration is the Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2 .
Install it in Package Manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspnNet.Razor -v 3.2.2
```

Configure your compiler for aspnet 4.6.2. You can use *.cshtml pages.
I try with the 3.2.3 bu not work.
You also must add this line in web.config in the `<appSettings>` section:

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

Anyone have a better Idea how to configure that?